# Converting characters from MySQL Database to standard characters

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have a database which contains some blocks of text. These text blocks contain extended characters such as: `’ ‘ … “ and ”`. When displayed directly to a web page they all show like this: �.

I've tried doing as str_replace to show normal characters, with no luck.
I've tried iconv, which will only work when set to ignore, which makes the punctuation look wrong.
I've tried html_encode, which also doesn't work. (I'm also using the parsedown script to format the text.)

The funny thing is, the website I'm replacing supports these characters fine, so I don't know what I'm doing wrong! (I don't have access to this website, or source code, or database, which is why I'm replacing it!)

Can anyone provide any help??

I just want to stop showing � and start showing proper characters!

Comment: I didn't see that article earlier, but this has resolved my issue! many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the above linked article, this issue is now resolved.

I firstly changed the collation of all of my tables as follows:

> Specify the utf8mb4 character set on all tables and text columns in
>   your database.

Then in my php code where it connects to the database, I added this line:

```
$CONNECTION -> set_charset('utf8mb4');
```

All issues resolved! Thanks to all who contributed to my fix!